# Refresh on protected Routes React Router with firebase auth

Tags: reactjs, react-router, firebase-authentication, react-redux, react-router-v4

I'm building a todo web app using firebase, react and redux. So I have protected rotes such as `"/todos/add"`, `"/dashboard"` and  guests Routes as `"/"`,`"/signup"`, `"/login"` which can't be accessed if you're are authenticated.

My problem is when I'm authenticated in the `"/todos/add"` route and I reload the page the app reloads and my auth actions are dispatched putting my user in the redux store, but I'm redirect to `"/login"` an then to `"/dashboard"`. but I want to be on the same page before the reload. my code:

PrivateRoute.js

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const PrivateRoute = ({
  isAuthenticated,
  isLoading,
  component: Component,
  ...rest
}) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props =>
      isAuthenticated ? (
        <Component {...props} {...rest} />
      ) : (
        <Redirect to="/login" />
      )
    }
  />
);
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  isAuthenticated: !!state.user.uid,
  isLoading: state.user.isLoading
 });

PrivateRoute.propTypes = {
  component: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  isAuthenticated: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
   isLoading: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PrivateRoute);
```

GuestRoute.js

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const GuestRoute = ({ isAuthenticated, component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props =>
      !isAuthenticated ? (
        <Component {...props} />
      ) : (
        <Redirect
          to="/dashboard"
        />
      )
    }
  />
);

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  isAuthenticated: !!state.user.uid,
  isLoading: !!state.user.isLoading
});

GuestRoute.propTypes = {
  component: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  isAuthenticated: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  isLoading: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(GuestRoute);
```

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

// COMPONENTS
import HomePage from "./components/pages/homepage/HomePage";
import SignupPage from "./components/pages/signuppage/SignupPage";
import LoginPage from "./components/pages/loginpage/LoginPage";
import DashboardPage from "./components/pages/dashboardpage/DashboardPage";

// HOC
import Layout from "./components/hoc/layout/Layout";

// ROUTES
import PrivateRoute from "./routes/PrivateRoute";
import GuestRoute from "./routes/GuestRoute";
import AddTodosPage from "./components/pages/todos/add/AddTodosPage";

const App = () => (
  <Layout>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" exact component={HomePage} />
      <GuestRoute path="/signup" exact component={SignupPage} />
      <GuestRoute path="/login" exact component={LoginPage} />
      <PrivateRoute path="/todos/add" exact component={AddTodosPage} />
      <PrivateRoute path="/dashboard" exact component={DashboardPage} />
    </Switch>
  </Layout>
);

export default App;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**FIX**
 Set `isLoading` to `true` by default, which would be the value at refresh. (Set `isLoading` to `false` after firebase authentication.) And condition in `<PrivateRoute>` should be `(isLoading || isAuthenticated )`. 
**But Important :** Here `isLoading` and `isAuthenticated` should be set together after firebase authentication response. Or `isAuthenticated` should be set accordingly before `isLoading` is set to `false`.
**Explanation**
As soon as you refresh in `<PrivateRoute>` of `/todos/add`, it'll look for `isAuthenticated` value. Here seems it's `false`, and therefore will be redirected to `/login` route. 
 When in `<GuestRoute>` of `/login`, it'll again look at `!isAuthenticated` value. By this time `isAuthenticated` value seems to be `true` making it redirect back to `/dashboard`.
So from this observation it can be seen that `isAuthenticated` value is not set to `true` as soon as refreshed. But rather this firebase authentication request is asynchronous action, where there will be some notable in response. But before the response, redirecting happens taking default `isAuthenticated` value or `undefined` as value. In-between this re-directions, firebase authentication call will be done and set `isAuthenticated` to `true` for the final redirection to `/dashboard`.
 But here make use of `isLoading` value to delay redirections.  Set `isLoading` to `true` by default, which would be the value at refresh. (Set `isLoading` to `false` after firebase authentication.) And condition in `<PrivateRoute>` should be `(isLoading || isAuthenticated )`. **IMPORTANT :** Here `isLoading` and `isAuthenticated` should be set together after firebase authentication response. Or `isAuthenticated` should be set accordingly before `isLoading` is set to `false`. (Else if `isLoading` set to `false` and if `isAuthenticated` still remains `false` or `undefined` it'll be redirected!)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of rendering your route, try to render something like 'a loading state'.
Otherwise you will end up displaying your private route to an unauthenticated user if the auth call takes some time to resolve.

```
const PrivateRoute = ({
  component: Component,
  permission: Permission,
  waitingForAuth: Waiting,
  ...rest
}) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props => {
      if (Waiting) return <LinearProgress />;
      return Permission ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/" />;
    }}
  />
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue with my stack (firebase + vuex + vuejs). My solution was to add a `userLoading` State to my store, which is a `Promise<void>;`.

My design is to pass the auth instance to my store state constructor and resolve the `userLoading` promise when the auth state changes.

My route uses `await` for the promise, then checks if there is a user.

Here is my state constructor:

```
 public constructor(auth: firebase.auth.Auth) {
    this.user = auth.currentUser;
    this.userLoading = new Promise(resolve => {
        auth.onAuthStateChanged(async (user: firebase.User | null) => {
            if (user) {
                await user!.getIdToken(true);
                const decodedToken = await user!.getIdTokenResult();

                this.stripeRole = decodedToken.claims.stripeRole;
            }

            this.user = user;
            resolve();
        });
    });
}
```